# Wordpress check if theme is a child using stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent-child, stylesheet

I want to check if specific theme is a child theme using stylesheet.

For exmaple:

```
$childBoolean = functionHere( 'twentyfifteen' );
```

I need some kind of function that checks if specific theme is a child. It should return a boolean.

So, is there a function that ckecks it ? Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might be useful if you know how to use it:

```
1486                    // Look in a parent theme first, that way child theme CSS overrides.
1487                    if ( is_child_theme() ) {
1488                            $template_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
1489                            **$template_dir = get_template_directory();**
1490    
1491                            foreach ( $editor_styles as $key => $file ) {
1492                                    if ( $file && file_exists( "$template_dir/$file" ) ) {
1493                                            $stylesheets[] = "$template_uri/$file";
1494                                    }
1495                            }
1496                    }
```

(from: [wp-includes/theme.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L0), via link in AllysonSouza's comment.
I imagine you should be able to get the template directory name using some of those php commands or pulling the variable, which is almost always the theme name.

$template_dir or get_template_directory();

Also, the following could probably be used:

```
128 /**
129  * Whether a child theme is in use.
130  *
131  * @since 3.0.0
132  *
133  * @return bool true if a child theme is in use, false otherwise.
134  **/
135 function is_child_theme() {
136         return ( **TEMPLATEPATH** !== STYLESHEETPATH );
137 }
```

The pertinent variable(?) being TEMPLATEPATH I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_child_theme()` to check if the current theme is a child of another. The function documentations is here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_child_theme

Comment: I don't need to check the current theme